# My phone is low on power,it has low power

Tags: word-usage

If my phone's  battery will die soon(run out of juices), what should I use(if any of the sentences below sound natural)

> My phone has **low power.**
>
> My phone is **low on power.**

So either of those sentences sound natural? If not then what are the natural alternatives?

So what would natives use when the phone is going to switch off?

Comment: Related question on ELU: [No charge on my cellphone](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10084/i-have-no-charge-on-my-cellphone-or-my-cellphone-is-out-of-charge)

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to say something like:

My battery is low.
I need to charge my battery.
My battery is about dead.
My phone is about dead. 
My phone is almost dead. 
My phone needs recharging. (Suggested by J.R. in comment)

> My phone has low power.

This is understandable. There could be a bit of ambiguity. "My phone has low power" could be taken to mean that your battery charge is running down, or could it mean that your phone just puts out a weak signal, no matter how high the battery charge state is. What I'm trying to say is "has low power" could imply that it is a permanent characteristic of the phone and not just temporary because of the battery charge. I don't think a native speaker would tend to use this.

> My phone is low on power.

This is understandable, but probably would not come as readily to the lips of a native American English speaker as the alternatives I gave you.

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but your answer pretty much covers everything I was going to say. One other alternative I might suggest is: _My phone needs recharging._